How to Prevent Confirm Resubmission Popup on Page Reload in Flask Application?
Intro
I am developing a Flask application where users can submit feedback through a form. After submitting the form, I want to redirect users to the home page instead of showing a confirm resubmission popup when they reload the page.
Problem
I am encountering the following issues:

When I reload the page after form submission, a confirm resubmission popup appears.
I want to ensure that the user is redirected to the home page instead of seeing this popup.
Additionally, I want to implement feedback buttons (thumbs up and thumbs down) that visually indicate which button was selected."

Code snippets
Here’s the relevant code from my app.py file:
@app.route("/",methods=['get', 'post'])
def index():
 form = userinput()
 if request.method == 'POST':
   connect = apiurl
   resp = requests.post(connect)
   url = resp.json()['url']
   message = resp.json()['text']
   return render_template(home.html, title = 'index', form=form, url=url, message=message)
return render_template(index.html, form=form)

forms.py
class UserInput(FlaskForm):
    text = TextAreaField('Enter your Question ', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Request for the Answer')
    feedback = StringField('Feedback')

index.html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<!--    <h1>Home Page</h1>-->
<!--    <span>Request Method - {{ request_method }}</span>-->
{% endblock content %}

Here’s the feedback button implementation in home.html:
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <ul class = "label-for-list"> Files:
            <li class="list"><a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class ="second">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Answer: </label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="12">{{ message }}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="feedback-button">
            {{ form.feedback.label(class="form-label") }}
            <input type="button" value="" class="emoticon" title="thumbs-up" onclick="console.log('Positive')" onmousedown="mousedown()" onmouseup="mouseup()">
            <input type="button" value="" class="emoticon" title="thumbs-down" onclick="console.log('Negative')">
        </div>
        <script>
            function mousedown(input){
                input.style.color = "blue";
            }
        </script>

{% endblock content %}

layout.html
<div class="container">
        <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" action="/">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.text.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {{ form.text(class="form-control form-control-lg",rows="5") }}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group d-grid gap-2">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>

api.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from wonderwords import RandomSentence
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def func():
    print(request.method)
    if(request.method == 'GET'):
        response = "This is just GET request and API is up and running"
        return jsonify({'response': response})

    elif(request.method == 'POST'):
        data = request.data.decode('utf-8')
        url = f"https:\\SourceDir\\file{random.randint(0,10)}.pdf"
        s = RandomSentence()
        # d = {"text":data.strip('\"'),'URL':url}
        d = {"text": s.sentence(), "URL": url}
        return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run(debug=True)
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

Questions

How can I prevent the confirm resubmission popup from appearing when the page is reloaded after form submission?
What is the best way to implement feedback buttons that visually indicate which button is selected?

I would appreciate any insights or examples that can help me resolve these issues effectively. Thank you!"

I am going to assume you want a way to redirect people once they click on your feedback button , you just need to modify your index function with the redirect function. I am assuming you have a home function like you have for your index function
from flask import redirect, url_for, flash

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = UserInput()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        connect = apiurl
        resp = requests.post(connect)
        url = resp.json()['url']
        message = resp.json()['text']

        # store the results using Flask's session/flash
        flash({'url': url, 'message': message})
        
        # redirect to /home after processing the form 
        return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

@app.route("/home", methods=['GET'])
def home():
    form = UserInput()

    # show results from flash
    data = dict(session) if 'data' in session else None
    if not data:
        flash('No data')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
        
    url = data.get('url')
    message = data.get('message')

    return render_template('home.html', form=form, url=url, message=message)


You also need to write a script in JS to listen to events such as clicks by getting the id of the buttons.
 <script>
   function sendFeedback(action) {
      const thumbsUp = document.getElementById('thumbsup');
      const thumbsDown = document.getElementById('thumbsdown');
            
      if (action === 'up') {
        // change the colour when a up button is clicked
           thumbsUp.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            thumbsDown.style.backgroundColor = '';
     } if (action === 'down') {
           // change the colour when a down button is clicked
            thumbsDown.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
            thumbsUp.style.backgroundColor = '';
          }
      }
 </script>


Add the function to your your home.html file
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <ul class="label-for-list"> 
        Files:
        <li class="list"><a href="{{ url }}">{{ url }}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="second">
        <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Answer: </label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="25">{{ message }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-button">
        {{ form.feedback.label(class="form-label") }}
        <input type="button" value="" class="emoticon" title="thumbs-up" onclick="sendFeedback(this)">
        <input type="button" value="" class="emoticon" title="thumbs-down" onclick="sendFeedback(this)">
    </div>
{% endblock content %}


Thanks for the response, my bad i wrote it as home page instead i want to redirect it to index page. i am getting confirm resubmission form pop up on home page once i reload but i want it to land on index page.

You are most welcome, yeah that is easy just replace the home in redirect function to your preferred page, i.e index or your preferred page. redirect(url_for('index')). Please if this works for you can you mark the answer as correct thanks

It is not working as expected , thanks for the response though. the problem maybe in the way i asked the question, apologies. So I am trying to create a simple UI with input text and then when I hit on submit it gives me answer which is the response from api. Home page should give me the answers to the question ( which is the input) so in home page I should see the input given along with submit button and answer . when I get the answer and reload the page I need to see index page so that the user enters the next question, once i reload the page i get confirm resubmission popup in current code.

@SanjanaHongunti are you talking about something which displays the answer back to the user and when there is a refresh/reload , you only see the index page which has your input? Something like a flash in FLask

yeah , when there is a refresh/reload I want to see the index page asking for input but i see confirm resubmission pop-up.

ok, I have made changes to it let us see what happens
